# unixODBC: invalid handle when handle is allocated in a Haskell thread

Tags: multithreading, haskell, odbc, unixodbc

I am building an ODBC application in Haskell, using foreign calls. When calling odbc functions in forkIO or forkOS thread (ie unbounded or bounded thread) on handles allocated in the same thread, the function returns invalid handle error.

The same call works perfect when made in the main thread.

Comment: Do you use a db connection or a db pool, maybe you need more connection handles, the latter shares between threads, if you use a single connection you must create one for each thread

Comment: @epsilonhalbe - i am using a different connection for each thread; i tried using a different environment for each thread; it seems that it is a bug in unixODBC on 64 bit platforms; if a handle is allocated in the main thread, then it will work, if it is allocated on a thread different then the main thread, they will not work, and I guess this will happen only on 64 bit platforms; I am still doing some research, I am not sure yet

Comment: Very strange! If you can go for the connection pool, I believe it is more economic. Have you checked the db settings on how many open connections it allows? (Just to make sure)

Comment: Meanwhile I have done my research, and it is indeed a bug in unixODBC. It returns as handlers the value of the pointer used for data structure that is behind the handler. In 32 bit systems, this is a 32 bit integer, but in 64 bit systems, it is truncated. So, in my case, for example for the handler with value 0xc8000c50, unixODBC allocated a data structure at the address 0x7f89c8000c50. When calling a function on this handler, it try to use it as the address of the structure, and, obviously, it fails.

Comment: I think this is not a comment but an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem is caused by a bug in unixODBC, I documented it here: https://sourceforge.net/p/unixodbc/bugs/41/

In a few words, unixODBC uses as handles pointers to memory allocated to keep data for those handles. As handles are 32 bit integers, on 64 bit architectures they are truncated to the last significant half (for x86 processors).

Thus, if the pointer value is less than 2G, everything is ok, but if it is more than 2G (and not 4G due to the fact that the sign bit extends) then unixODBC will not be able to locate the data structure for the handle and will report invalid handle.

When SQLAllocHandle is called from Haskell in the main thread, the allocated pointer has a value less than 2G, so everything works. But when it is called from another thread (liftIO or liftOS), the allocated pointer has a value larger than 2G, so multithreaded ODBC applications using unixODBC are not possible in Haskell unless all the handles allocation is done in the main thread.

The workaround I found is based on the fact that, in the main thread I have a function that waits for the work in the threads to complete. I modified that function to also listen for a channel for handle allocation requests and then allocate the handle and return the response.

This is the sample code I used for workarround:

```
-- All actions are ReaderT monad actions that share a global environment
-- for threads execution

-- | wait for worker threads to complete the work
waitForWorkToEnd :: (MonadIO m) => ReaderT MyEnvironment m ()
waitForWorkToEnd = do
  threadsCountVar <- asks threads_WorkerThreadsVar
  allocHandleChan <- asks threads_AllocHandleChan

  let waitIO = join $ atomically $ orElse (readTVar threadsCountVar >>= check . (<= 0) >> (return $ return ())) (allocHandleT allocHandleChan >>= \ io -> return (io >> waitIO))
  liftIO $ waitIO
  liftIO $ log $ fromString $ "all worker threads have finished"

-- | creates an IO action inside a STM monad to allocate a new handler in the current thread
allocHandleT :: (MonadIO m, MonadFail m) => TQueue (SQLSMALLINT, SQLINTEGER, TMVar SQLINTEGER) -> STM (m ())
allocHandleT chan = do
  (hType, hParent, retVar) <- readTQueue chan
  return $ allocHandle hType hParent >>= liftIO . atomically . (putTMVar retVar) 

-- | make a handle alloc request to the main thread and wait for result
allocHandleReq :: (MonadIO m, MonadFail m) => SQLSMALLINT -> SQLINTEGER -> ReaderT MyEnvironment m SQLINTEGER
allocHandleReq htype hparent = do
  allocHandleChan <- asks threads_AllocHandleChan
  resultVar       <- liftIO $ atomically $ newEmptyTMVar
  liftIO $ atomically $ writeTQueue allocHandleChan (htype, hparent, resultVar)
  liftIO $ atomically $ takeTMVar resultVar

-- allocHandle simply calls SQLAllocHandle and takes care of the diagnostics 
-- information; it is part of the sqlcli package you can find it here:
-- https://hub.darcs.net/mihaigiurgeanu/sqlcli
```